# If $|z| = 2$. Then Locus of $z$ Representing The Complex no. $-1+5z,$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $|z| = 2$. Then Locus of $z$ Representing The Complex no. $-1+5z,$ is

$\underline{\bf{My\;\; Try::}}$ Let $z^{'} = -1+5z$, Where $z^{'} = x^{'}+iy^{'}$. So put  $5z = z^{'}+1$ in $|z| = 2\Leftrightarrow |5z| = 10$

$|z^{'}-(-1+0\cdot i)| = 10$, means Locus of Conplex no. $z^{'}$ is a Circle with Center at $(-1,0)$

and Radious $ = 10$

Is it Right OR Not, If Not . The please explain me Righta answer.

Comment: Yes; multiplying by 5 is a dilation, and adding is a translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done! Your reasoning is spot on!

Comment: Thanks Cameron Buie.......